# How to embed hd video in YouTube iframe

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, embed

My code right now looks like this:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6X3zUh8RqbY?hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I read here and elsewhere that the ?hd=1 part should turn it to hd, however this doesn't work for me. The video is embedded as 360p...

Comment: What is the point of having a high resolution video in a tiny frame? It will just be scaled down. Downloading it would be a waste of bandwidth and decoding it would be a waste of processing power. If the user full screens it, then YouTube's player will switch quality automatically.

Comment: +1. I had the exact same problem last week, but none of the fixes worked. (Also, welcome to S.O.)

Comment: It looks crappy because youtube also reduces the quality overall when downscaling the video.

Comment: Read this http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178264

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6X3zUh8RqbY&ap=%2526fmt%3D22" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Method found at

http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-embed-and-play-720p-hd-high-definition-youtube-videos-fmt22-code-hack/

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>`

iFrame video and audio is encoded using lossy compression. Only intraframe compression is enabled; every frame is a stand-alone i-frame. The width and height set the size of the video that will be uploaded.
example:

Comment: please add some explanation to your code, this will help others who see your answer in the future